# python queue.Queue(block=True, timeout=.001) has 9-13 ms delay in windows vs Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have found that using timeout with a python queue.Queue() results in an 9-13ms delay in Windows over Ubuntu in python 3.6.5

Does that make sense?

```
import datetime
import queue

q = queue.Queue()
print(datetime.datetime.now())
try:
    msg = q.get(block=True, timeout=.001)
except:
    print(datetime.datetime.now())  

Window 10, Python 3.6.5
2018-08-28 02:20:20.374122
2018-08-28 02:20:20.388434
time 14ms

Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.6.5
2018-08-28 06:21:01.305297
2018-08-28 06:21:01.306404
time 1.1ms
```